# Trying to find the syntax for multiplying DateDiff * number of rent days, then add to the amount due column

Tags: sql, datediff

Write a query to assign values to the `Amount_Due` column in the `Transaction` row based on the `Price` of the `Car` and the number of days of the rent.

The amount due will be calculated as (Price * number of days),
Number of days can be calculated by using pickup and return dates.

I have found how to calculate the `Number of days`:

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(d, PickupDate, ReturnDate) AS 'Number of days', CAR.Price, Amount_Due
 FROM [TRANSACTION]
 INNER JOIN CAR ON CAR.CarID = [TRANSACTION].CarID
```

But I tried to assign the values back with this statement, but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(d, PickupDate, ReturnDate) AS 'Number of days', CAR.Price, Amount_Due
 FROM [TRANSACTION]
 INNER JOIN CAR ON CAR.CarID = [TRANSACTION].CarID
 WHERE Price * DATEDIFF(d, PickupDate, ReturnDate) = Amount_Due;
```

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [TRANSACTION] ( 
    tID int PRIMARY KEY, 
    cID int REFERENCES CUSTOMER(cID), 
    CarID int REFERENCES CAR(CarID), 
    eID int REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(eID), 
    tDate date NOT NULL, 
    PickupDate date NOT NULL, 
    ReturnDate date NOT NULL
); 
CREATE TABLE CAR ( 
    CarID int PRIMARY KEY, 
    Make varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
    Model varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
    type varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    year date NOT NULL, 
    Price Mmoney NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query will return the `Number of days` but you have not done any *Assignment*. To do that you will need to write an update statement.

Before we go that step, make sure you have correctly calculated the Expected `Amount_Due` by including your calculation output and the input fields in a single select:

```
SELECT PickupDate, 
       ReturnDate,
       DATEDIFF(d, PickupDate, ReturnDate) AS 'Number of days',
       CAR.Price, 
       Car.Price * DATEDIFF(d, PickupDate, ReturnDate) as Amount_Due
FROM [TRANSACTION]
INNER JOIN CAR ON CAR.CarID = [TRANSACTION].CarID
```

If the amount due matches your expectation then the following `UPDATE` statement could be used

```
UPDATE [TRANSACTION]
    SET Amount_Due = Car.Price * DATEDIFF(d, t.PickupDate, t.ReturnDate)
FROM [TRANSACTION] t
INNER JOIN CAR ON CAR.CarID = t.CarID
```

> This solution is tested against MS SQL Server, your RDBMS might have slightly different syntax for `UPDATE` that has joins, in MySQL for instance the `JOIN` needs to be specified before `SET`

This query will update all records, in the *real world* you would limit this with some specific criteria, like where the `Amount_Due IS NULL` or there would be some sort of criteria on the transaction or the car where you would no longer want to update the transaction.